# SQL Server 2008 R2 standard missing "Audits" folder in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, audit

I will pre-cursor this with the fact that I am NOT a DBA!

I am trying to set up auditing on an SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition, but the Audits folder is missing from the Security section.

Is this a version issue associated with the "fine-grained auditing" that is only in the Enterprise and DataCenter editions?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

According to [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Enterprise_security) auditing is only available in 2008 / 2008 R2 Enterprise / Datacenter.

According to [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.110%29.aspx#Enterprise_security) auditing has been split up in SQL Server 2012, so that basic auditing is now offered in Standard Edition.

So what you're seeing is expected: prior to SQL Server 2012, auditing was an Enterprise-only feature (outside of C2/CCC, which is just sp_configure stuff that is not exposed in Object Explorer).