# Security table access logging

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, logging

I am new to SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. I need to log select access, on a given table. I need to log the requested data and the user who executed the select statement. Or log the user and the select statement.

I have tried looking on the web, but it's seems like it's hard to find anything involving the select statement.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are talking about monitoring or auditing the SELECT statements. A search with those terms will give you a lot to start with.

General information on the subject: [An introduction to SQL Server2008 audit](http://www.bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/), by Brad M McGehee

More info on MSSQLTips.com, some samples using tSQL: [SQL Server 2008 TSQL Auditing Commands for SELECT statements](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1655/sql-server-2008-tsql-auditing-commands-for-select-statements/). [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) also you have some more info, search for `auditing` to see what each version allows to do. And on [this other page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) you have a very detailed info

**EDIT:**

For SQL Server 2008 & 2008R2 Standard editions there is no auditing capabilities, on SQL Server 2012 Standard edition yes we have, check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145967/sql-server-2008-r2-standard-missing-audits-folder-in-ssms) for more details. So for SQL2008 you must rely on [DDL's triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) to audit CRUD operations. And for `SELECT` statements you must do it manually. Check [this post on SQLServeCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1187965-1550-1.aspx).

**Edit2**
What SQL Server 2012 Express edition covers on auditing? By doing a quick search on google, [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Using-filtering-and-server-audit-specs-to-audit-DB-objects-in-SQL-Server-2012.aspx) 
 and [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Auditing-database-level-objects-in-SQL-Express-2012.aspx)

Comment: The Audit on Select statements is only allowed in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition. Is there another way og loggin Select on a given table, in SQL Server Standard Edition ?

Comment: It's only on select I need to log, not on CRUD. I know there is no triggers for select and the use of SP is no option. Now I'm trying with EVENT SESSION, but I log all select queries and not on a specific table.

Comment: What does Basic Auditing in SQL Server 2012 cover? It's hard to se the difference om MS

Comment: edited once more to add several links related to SQL2012 express auditing

Comment: The links are pointing to the same page on same site.
On the refered link it's not possible to se if this i standard og interprise SQL Server 2012, Bob is writing about.
I know the sample code for audit on select, it's taken from SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

Comment: Then I do not see how you can do it by plain scripts, other than what @Damien_the_unbeliever suggested, but you can't restrict users access to tables. On [MSDN as I posted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) there is lot of information on SQL2012 audinting subject, take a deep look, there is only 7min difference between my edit and you asking about what SQL2012 auditing covers and then 21min after 2nd edit, take a deep breath and spend couple of hours (or more) reading and doing more research...is just an advice, don't get me wrong

Comment: I have to use SQL Server 2008, and no stored procedures, and no SQL Server 2012. 
 
I think the right solution is to use Extended Events and the listen on sqlserver.sql_statement_starting for doing the logging. It seams like a solution, with overhead in logging, but will do the job. 
 
I will use Auditing if / when, changing to SQL Server 2012

Comment: @HansClausen - The overhead of logging is small compared to the fact that your users can run arbitrary queries on your server that could bring it to its knees.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, The setup is like, each customer have there own server, I just have to ensure that access to a few tables are logged, for safety reasons. In case of an audit, we will look in the log. What they do or how much load they make is not a concern. I need to have options on the DB as open as possible, because there are different clients (apps) accessing the data, for instance a GIS client or a reporting client, where the customer make there own query and so on.

Comment: Thanx for all the expert answers. Hope to be able to contribute with knowledge some other time.

Answer (score 0):

Deny users `select` permissions on the tables.

Create stored procedures through which they can run the queries they need to run. Add any necessary auditing into the body of the stored procedures.

Comment: Can'do, users have access to all db tables, to build the query they want.